# Merge two or more XML node using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

This is the input file:

```
<root> 
    <node id="N1">
        <fruit id="1" action="aaa">
            <orange id="x" action="create">
                <attribute>
                    <color>Orange</color>
                    <year>2012</year>
                </attribute>
            </orange>
            <orange id="x" action="change">
                <attribute>
                    <color>Red</color>
                </attribute>
            </orange>
            <orange id="x" action="change">
                <attribute>
                    <color>Blue</color>
                    <condition>good</condition>
                </attribute>
            </orange>
        </fruit>

    </node>

    <node id="N2">
        <car id="1">    
            <bmw id="i" action="change">
                <attribute>
                    <color>Blue</color>    
                </attribute>
            </bmw>      
            <bmw id="i" action="change">
                <attribute>
                    <color>Yellow</color>    
                </attribute>
            </bmw>
            <bmw id="i" action="change">
                <attribute>
                    <color>Pink</color>    
                </attribute>
            </bmw>


        <bmw id="j" action="delete">
            <attribute>
                <color>Blue</color>    
            </attribute>
        </bmw>
        <bmw id="j" action="delete">
            <attribute>
                <color>Yellow</color>    
            </attribute>
        </bmw>

    </car>
    </node>
</root>
```

This is the expected output:

```
<root> 
    <node id="N1">
        <fruit id="1" action="aaa">
            <orange id="x" action="create">
                <attribute>
                    <color>Blue</color>
                    <year>2012</year>
                    <condition>good</condition>
                </attribute>
            </orange>                      
        </fruit>       
    </node>

    <node id="N2">
        <car id="1">    

            <bmw id="i" action="change">
                <attribute>
                    <color>Pink</color>    
                </attribute>
            </bmw>


        <bmw id="j" action="delete">
            <attribute>
                <color>Yellow</color>    
            </attribute>
        </bmw>
      </car>
    </node>
</root>
```

The rule:

1. if there is node with 'create' method followed by one or more 'change' method, we merge them together and use ALL children from the last 'change' into the node with 'create' method. (Note: good is added )
2. if there is one or more 'change' method we merge them and use only children from the last  'change' method.
3. if there  is one or more 'delete' method we merge them and use only children from the last  'delete' method.

Note that the id must be the same for node to be merged.

Please advise me on XSLT solution for this problem. 
Thanks so much.

kind regards,
John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
     <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
     <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

     <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
     </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="node/*/*[1]">
      <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | ../*[last()]/*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
     </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match=
      "node/*/*
        [@action='delete'
       and
         following-sibling::*[1][@action='delete']
        ]"/>

     <xsl:template match=
      "node/*/*
        [@action='change'
       and
         following-sibling::*[1][@action='change']
       or
         preceding-sibling::*[@action='create']
        ]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<root>
    <node id="N1">
        <fruit id="1" action="aaa">
            <orange id="x" action="create">
                <attribute>
                    <color>Orange</color>
                </attribute>
            </orange>
            <orange id="x" action="change">
                <attribute>
                    <color>Red</color>
                </attribute>
            </orange>
            <orange id="x" action="change">
                <attribute>
                    <color>Blue</color>
                    <condition>good</condition>
                </attribute>
            </orange>
        </fruit>
    </node>
    <node id="N2">
        <car id="1">
            <bmw id="i" action="change">
                <attribute>
                    <color>Blue</color>
                </attribute>
            </bmw>
            <bmw id="i" action="change">
                <attribute>
                    <color>Yellow</color>
                </attribute>
            </bmw>
            <bmw id="i" action="change">
                <attribute>
                    <color>Pink</color>
                </attribute>
            </bmw>
            <bmw id="j" action="delete">
                <attribute>
                    <color>Blue</color>
                </attribute>
            </bmw>
            <bmw id="j" action="delete">
                <attribute>
                    <color>Yellow</color>
                </attribute>
            </bmw>
        </car>
    </node>
</root>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<root>
   <node id="N1">
      <fruit id="1" action="aaa">
         <orange id="x" action="create">
            <attribute>
               <color>Blue</color>
               <condition>good</condition>
            </attribute>
         </orange>
      </fruit>
   </node>
   <node id="N2">
      <car id="1">
         <bmw id="i" action="change">
            <attribute>
               <color>Pink</color>
            </attribute>
         </bmw>
         <bmw id="j" action="delete">
            <attribute>
               <color>Yellow</color>
            </attribute>
         </bmw>
      </car>
   </node>
</root>
```

Comment: not sure you should have accounted for this case but if the last two `bmw`s where `create` followed by a `change` the transformation would use the `create` node with its children. It would be easy to fix wrapping these two "orphaned" `bmw` nodes into a `car` parent like the other ones, but not sure how much control there is over the input file.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev Hi, I'm sorry could you make a slight update on the solutions. Because the </car> should be at the bottom. Also i accidentally put the wrong method name. It should only have 'change' not modify. Thank you.

Comment: @Pavel Veller thank you for pointing that out. yes the </car> should be at the bottom like you said. My mistake.

Comment: with the wrapping `car` around those `bmw`s Dimitre's solution will work as you expect it to. The modify vs. change "spelling issue" can be corrected by renaming it in those predicates. What wonders me more though is whether you might have more complex scenarios. It wasn't spelled out in the summary but is that possible that change/modify events accumulate fields and you would then need to build a superset (right now it just takes child elements from the last one). also, whether you might have different entities mixed together thus would need to match by `@id` and not the relative position.

Comment: @PavelVeller I have tried to rename it but it's not working, I think it's because the change of depth level.

Comment: @John: I edited the solution and now it works with your changed problem.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev Hi, I'm sorry but i've been focusing on simplifying my question that I forgot to mention that we must keep the existing node intact. Please see my edited (orange id=x) it has year (2012) attribute and we want to keep it. Could you advise me on that?

Comment: @John: I feel tired of editing the answer after the original question has been changed so many times. Please: 1. In this specific case, ask a new question. 2. Always think well before asking a question so that you'll not have to modify the question so many times once asked. 3. Provide well-formed XML. 4. Verify that the provided data is semantically correct. 5. Provide representative data that doesn't need to be augmented multiple times. 6. Explain the structure and meaning of the data. 7. Explain the requirements that the transformation must implement. 8. The data shouldn't need scrolling.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev I really apologize for the trouble. It won't happen again.